# Who sends Autonegotiation FLPs first in a link at 1000BaseT

Tags: ethernet, autonegotiation

In 1000BaseT the same pairs of wires (all four pair) are used both for transmission and reception. In this gigabit mode how is it decided which of the link partners will send FLPs first. Further what happens if both the link partners send FLPs at the same time?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The link pulses are always sent on the transmit pair for 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX even on a 1000BASE-T port.

This creates a problem only when two ports with the same pinout - MDI vs MDI-X - are connected to each other, but the practically standard Auto MDI-X algorithm (more or less) alternates the transmit and receive pairs, so eventually the pulses will find the right path and the link can be brought up.

1000BASE-T also needs to figure out which pairs are connected to each other (straight cable, two-pair crossover cable, four-pair crossover cable). This is done in the physical coding sublayer (PCS).

Comment: In 1000BaseT simultaneous transmission occurs in both directions by using echo cancellation. In this is case both the link partners are transmitting over the same pair.

Comment: @ShreyasS Simultaneous transmission on all pair happens _once the link is established_. The pulses are required to _establish the link_ and work in the very same logic as with 100BASE-TX. It explicitly uses the same fashion defined in Clause 28 for 100BASE-T.

Answer (score -1):

From [*Gigabit Ethernet Auto-Negotiation*](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/power/en/ps1q01_hernan?c=us&l=en&cs=04), By Rich Hernandez (Issue 1 2001):

> ***The Auto-Negotiation standard allows devices based on several Ethernet standards, from 10BaseT to 1000BaseT, to coexist in the
>   network by mitigating the risks of network disruption arising from
>   incompatible technologies. This capability helps ensure a smooth
>   migration path from Ethernet to Fast Ethernet and Gigabit Ethernet.
>   This article provides an in-depth explanation of auto-negotiation and
>   its functioning and also discusses special cases that may be
>   encountered.***
>
> Today a number of technologies, such as 10BaseT, 100BaseTX, and
>   1000BaseT, use the same RJ-45 connector, creating the potential for
>   connecting electrically incompatible components together and causing
>   network disruption. In addition, with the advent of Gigabit Ethernet
>   over copper, three-speed devices now support 10 Mbps, 100 Mbps, and
>   1000 Mbps operation. The Institute of Electrical and Electronics
>   Engineers (IEEE®) developed a method known as auto-negotiation to
>   eliminate the possibility of dissimilar  technologies interfering with
>   each other.
>
> Gigabit transceivers at the physical layer (PHY) of the Open Systems
>   Interconnection (OSI) model use auto-negotiation to advertise the
>   following modes of operation: 1000BaseT in full or half duplex,
>   100BaseTX in full or half duplex, and 10BaseT in full or half duplex.
>   Although auto- negotiation can be disabled for 100BaseTX or 10BaseT
>   connectivity, it is always required for normal 1000BaseT operation.
>
> Auto-negotiation enables an easy upgrade path to gigabit speeds by
>   future proofing the server network connectivity with a three-speed
>   network interface card (NIC) or LAN on motherboard (LOM). A server
>   connected to a Fast Ethernet switch or hub can easily be upgraded to
>   Gigabit Ethernet by connecting the NIC to a Gigabit Ethernet switch.
>   If both the NIC and the switch are set to auto-negotiate, the
>   interface will be automatically configured to run at 1000 Mbps.

Comment: Your post is a flat copy of the content of this page [Gigabit Ethernet Auto-Negotiation](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/power/en/ps1q01_hernan?c=us&l=en&cs=04). This could be considered plagiarism. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Always give credit where it is due. Presenting something without giving the author credit is stealing. I fixed it for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.